# vim:have multiple windows without splitting?

Tags: vim, window

is there any way I can have multiple windows in a terminal based vim, without splitting the window? so I could just switch to the other file by hitting a key ?

Comment: are you looking for multiple `buffers` in one vim instance? multiple `tabs` in one vim instance? multiple terminals in one window (`screen`)?

Comment: Vim calls them tabs or tabpages, you're probably just missing that terminology in order to look them up ;) http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html

Answer (score 2):

if "window" you meant is vim-window, the answer is no.

In vim, a window is a viewport onto a buffer.  You can use multiple windows on one
buffer, or several windows on different buffers.

So window is viewport, if you there is no splitting you are watching on single window, no multiple.

I guess what you meant is **buffer**: A buffer is a file loaded into memory for editing.  The original file remains unchanged until you write the buffer to the file.

You can have one window (without splitting) and 10 files(buffers). You could `:ls` to see the buffer list, and also by command to switch among those buffers/files. display them in single window.

you can get more info about switching files/buffers by:

```
:h buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use tabs.

To open a new tab you can use `:tabe <file>`. After that you can use `gt` or `gT` to move to the next or previous tab.

If you are opening a bunch of files from the command line you can use `vim -p <files>` to open them all in tabs.

Take a look at [`:h tab-page-commands`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#tab-page-commands)